# Creating Query in MySQL returns crazy figures

Tags: mysql

I can currently pull accurate figures should the bookings form be completed. However The 'DateIN' is to be completed at a later date due to the business scenario. If the booking is not completed then it throws my figures off completely.

In this situation the field is 1970/1/1 by default until updated. What I would like to do is ignore these fields somehow, I have been advised that perhaps changing the field to null until updated later on may fix my problem, however I have no idea how to do this.

Code is below.

```
SELECT
SUM((MatCost+TimeCost)+((DateIn-DateOut)*RentPD+((DateIn-DateDue)*10))-DepReq) AS TotalDue,
employee.Fname, employee.Sname
FROM booking
INNER JOIN customer ON booking.CustID = customer.CustID
INNER JOIN costume ON booking.CostID = costume.CostID
INNER JOIN employee ON booking.EmpID = employee.EmpID
GROUP BY employee.Fname, employee.Sname
ORDER BY TotalDue DESC
```

Comment: ...employee.EmpID **WHERE DateIn IS NOT NULL** GROUP BY...

Comment: thatll do, cheers man

Answer (score 0):

You can run an update query on DateIn field and set it to null wherever theres '1970/1/1'
ie.

```
update booking
set DateIn = null
where DateIn = '19700101'
```

and then in the above query

```
SELECT
SUM((MatCost+TimeCost)+((DateIn-DateOut)*RentPD+((DateIn-DateDue)*10))-DepReq) AS TotalDue,
employee.Fname, employee.Sname
FROM booking
INNER JOIN customer ON (booking.CustID = customer.CustID AND booking.DateIn is not null)
INNER JOIN costume ON booking.CostID = costume.CostID
INNER JOIN employee ON booking.EmpID = employee.EmpID
GROUP BY employee.Fname, employee.Sname
ORDER BY TotalDue DESC
```

I hope this helps..

Comment: Or you can just change your query by adding a where clause like 

   where DateIn <> '19700101'

Comment: hey, first thanks for the reply, but I have no idea where I would put the first statement

Comment: first statement as in?

Comment: update booking
set DateIn = null
where DateIn = '19700101'  Ive added this but the issue remains

Comment: You shouldn't make up data to represent a missing value - relational databases have null values explicitly to represent unknown data.

Comment: My problem is I want to compile a result based on populated queries but ignore the empty ones...I cannot acheive this without doing so

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to fix it, was a novice mistake on my part: the DateIn value should have been set as null by default. Amateur I know, but thanks both to Tejal and Symcbean for the help.